# Are Extended ASCII characters safe for filenames & folders?

Tags: windows, ascii, directory, filenames, extended-ascii

My C# project saves files and creates folders with the extended ASCII character "²" (superscript 2). Is this safe to work with internationally? Is this something that could cause any issues with the .NET libraries or Windows functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting windows NT (?) filenames are always unicode. so there shouldn't be a problem.

Things do get hairy when you start using alternative space characters, transliterated characters or characters which should have a bidirectional context but that is not the case with the superscript 2

Comment: So all modern Windows Versions (XP, Vista, 7) should use Unicode (UTF-16) and will be able to handle files & folders with the ² character?